# TensorFlow estimator.predict: Saving when as_iterable=True

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have modified the [Wide and Deep tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.html) (running python 2.7) to use a regressor instead of a classifier, and to output the predictions of my test data. I currently do this (import numpy as np):

```
predicts = m.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test))
np.savetxt("predict.csv", predicts, delimiter=",")
```

With the latest r0.11 version, I am getting a warning about upcoming deprecation in which the return value will be an iterable. To accommodate this, I attempted the following:

```
predicts = m.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test), as_iterable=True)
np.savetxt("predict.csv", list(predicts), delimiter=",")
```

This did not have the desired effect. The CPUs hit about 80% and stayed that way, seemingly indefinitely. I finally had to kill it after a half hour with no data written. What was it trying to do?

Any suggestions as to how I can get these predictions out to a text file when returned with `as_iterable=True`?

UPDATE:
I tried this:

```
predicts = m.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test), as_iterable=True)  
with open("predict.csv", "w") as f:
    for x in predicts:
      f.write(str(x)+"\n")
```

and the results seem to be the same. I suspect this is a bug. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `as_iterable` with `input_fn` is a little bit dangerous: If input_fn does not every complain about running out of new data, as_iterable will happily produce more and more output, usually running through the same input over and over again.

If you look at the `input_fn` in the Wide and Deep tutorial, you see that there are no queues in it, the data is put directly into constants. So no matter how often you pull on the tensors created by that `input_fn`, you will always get data.

as_iterable pulls on the inputs as long as it gets new data. In this case, that means forever.

This is a bug, an we should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have not changed the input behavior, so that is likely what is happening. For now I will use a hard `as_iterable=False`, but I will look into queuing and/or how to make it work with a different scheme than input_fn.

Comment: A fix for this is coming soon: We'll detect if you don't have any queues in the input_fn and stop after one call to it if we can't find any.